# how to insert copied text through textBox or anything in database same as it appears while copying the text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, html

I may copy text from a word file or notepad and I want it to be inserted in same text pattern as it appears in notepad or word file.

And I have to paste the copied text in textbox or anything that supports my need and then I insert that text in database and later on retrieve it and display on webpage using literal or anything that supports my need

Do I need anything instead of this textbox?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassage" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Wrap="true"   Width="586px" Height="200px"></asp:TextBox>
```

What Do I need more to display text as per my need

```
 Literal1.Text ="<pre>"+TextFrom database+"</pre>";
```

Comment: What problem you are facing when displaying code in `Literal1`?

Comment: Many kind of problems.Texts do not appear on screen in same pattern as in word file or notepad file. Some are in new row some in same row

Comment: you can try `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Your Data from datatbase")` function  in place of `TextFrom database` to display content in `Literal1.Text`

Answer (score 0):

You could get content from Word or Excel (or any other app) in html format

```
string data = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html)
```

You will get html string but with some header in front, look at the links below for examples how to handle it :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/21/html-clipboard.aspx

http://theartofdev.wordpress.com/2012/11/11/setting-html-and-plain-text-formatting-to-clipboard